# Retrieve standard NAME field label change through Metadata API

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, workbench, standard-field, customobjecttranslation

I have updated the standard NAME field's label on custom object through rename tabs and labels in Setup. But I am not able to retrieve the Name field label change.

Here is my package xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Product_Tag__c.Name</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Product_Tag__c-en_US</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```

Here is the output retrieved from Workbench:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <caseValues>
        <plural>false</plural>
        <value>Product Tag</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <plural>true</plural>
        <value>Product Tags</value>
    </caseValues>
    <startsWith>Consonant</startsWith>
</CustomObjectTranslation>
```

How can I retrieve the name field label change and deploy that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue and you would need to retrieve the object (Product_Tag__c) to update the standard field label.  You should be able to see something like below in your object file which has label name.

```
<nameField>
    <label>Product Tag Name</label>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Text</type>
</nameField>
```

Kindly review migration of standard fields limitation [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br9y).

Thanks